# Setting jEditable parameter

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working with jEdtable and would like to add 2 more parameters into the posted URL.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here's the default parameters -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
         id   : 'elementid',
         name : 'newvalue'
     });
 });
```

But I would like to add `pageName` to as parameter which will be posted along with the `id` and `name`.

I tried something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
         id   : 'elementid',
         name : 'newvalue',
         pageName: 'story'
     });
 });
```

But on the save.php page, pageName is not being displayed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use submitData (look at [this](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) link under "Parameter reference")

```
    "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
        return {
            "pageName": 'story',
            "column": '3'
        };
    },
```

Basically you can specify other parameters that will be sent to the server

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Editable's oUpdateParameters property

```
$('#datatable').dataTable().makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL: 'update.php',
    oUpdateParameters: {
        timeOfUpdate: function () {
            return Date.now();
        }
    }
});
```